# best way to make similar posts php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want code not cause load on server to find similar posts in php/mysql

I try with

```
MATCH (post) AGAINST ('string string')
```

but it was cause alot of load on server, so it stop my server for

**I have over 4,125,274 post in my database**

please help mE

Comment: What does your database look like?  Do you have 4 million records in one table?

Comment: Yes, vbulletin comments (posts)

Comment: I suppose you have a fulltext index on post?

Answer (score 4):

While Fulltext index will help, it will be still really slow if you want to load similar items many times. We have an implementation which has about 7 million records of posts with fulltext  and it takes maybe up to a minute to search if we only rely on mysql.

A good alternative is having a search server like sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/ which creates its own indexing and caching and is much much faster.
It is simple and efficient and is used by many big places like urbandictionary, craiglist, mozilla, etc.

If you want to do it in only mysql queries, and if you don't want to do one search many times, try caching the returned IDs on memcached.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you already have a fulltext index on post and this doesn't help you should consider incorporating a dedicated search engine on your posts, such as Lucene (not necessarily the php implementation though)